# Unit of time and normalization of time preference rates

Tags: dynamical-systems, optimal-control, differential-games

Consider an infinite horizon cake eating [differential game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_game) described by
\begin{align}
&\max_{u_1(t)} \int_0^\infty{e^{-r_1 t}\ln(u_1(t))dt}\\
&\max_{u_2(t)} \int_0^\infty{e^{-r_2 t}\ln(u_2(t))dt}\\
\text{s.t.} \quad &\dot x(t) = -u_1(t)-u_2(t)
\end{align}
where $t \in [0,\infty)$ refers to the current time, $u_i(t)$ to the consumption rate of player $i \in \{1,2\}$ and $x(t)$ to the size of the cake.

I'm interested in the time preference rates $r_i > 0$.
Without further explanations I found in Clemhout and Wan, 1989, On Games of cake-eating, p. 131

> Since one can always choose a unit for time without losing generality, we suppose that the length of a unit of time is such that the preference rates of the two players sum up to unity.

That is, we can normalize $r_1 + r_2 = 1$.
But what does this mean actually? I'm particular puzzled about the without loss of generality part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that $r_1>0$ and $r_2>0$. Let $r_i$ be such that $r_1+r_2=\rho$. By introducing a new independent variable $\tau=\rho t$ we get
$$\max_{u_1(\tau)} \frac{1}{\rho}\int_0^\infty{e^{-\frac{r_1}{\rho}\tau}\ln(u_1(\tau))d\tau}.$$
The factor $\frac{1}{\rho}$ in front of the integral can be dropped as it doesn't influence the result. And the new discount rates $\frac{r_i}{\rho}$ now sum to 1.